# Distributed server: Network connections

Tags: c#, networking, load-balancing, distributed-computing

I'm developing an application that should run on multiple machines with different tasks/roles, but synchronized (some kind of load balanced (game)server where some machines process the different worlds, one machine handles chat and inventories, other machines handle incoming network connections...).

Right at the beginning, the application instances should create TCP connections between each other. But how would I implement this in C#?

Comment: Why raw TCP connections? Why not use WCF or something a little higher in the framework. What have you tried?

Comment: @KingCronus It was maybe misconfigured, but my tests have shown that WCF is (even with the TCP binding) an order of magnitude slower than raw tcp.

Comment: Well sure there is overhead, but it is going to be more resilient (not to mention easier to program against) in the long run. Sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking how to use sockets in C#. Is there some reason opening TCP connections normally doesn't suit your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need the load balancing servers which can contact the correct gaming servers. That's probably the weakest point in the architecture. You can limit the risk by using DNS round robin and multiple load balancers.

If all your servers are placed on the same network you can use UDP broadcasting to allow the load balancers to automatically discover all game servers. The packets would be something like "Hey, I'm an inventory server, connect to me" where the load balancing server then would create a TCP connection which is solely used to monitor the game server (CPU usage etc to make sure that the server doesn't get too much work).